How to add a white background to a blender scene?
I'm working on achieving a completely white background (or possibly transparent, though I suspect that might not work well due to my transparent bottom cantilever). I've tried adjusting the light and saturation levels, but without success. Could you help me with this?
I've attached the image and Blender file to the post.



You can use an Emission shader instead of a Principled BSDF and it will be 100% white

@moonboots You could enable the Emission in the Principled BSDF as well. But if she leaves the Emission shader at its default Strength of 1, it will not be 100% white... more like 86% or so, because the Color Management is set to Filmic. In this case you need a Strength of 15 or 16 to get 100% white.

oh ok I didn't see the Filmic

Thank you so much both of you! It worked

Since you are using the Color Management set to View Transform > Filmic, the colors' dynamic range is not the same as in Standard. Therefore, "normal" white is always slightly darker. The following workaround is for the filmic transform set to Look > None, changing it to something with more or less contrast might require different values.
First of all you could give the plane an Emission shader or give it Emission inside the Principled BSDF node, however due to the Filmic setting a Strength of 1 will not be sufficient to make it white (RGB = 255/255/255 in the PNG file). Real white needs a Strength around 15 or better 16 to be safe.
But this will make the glass part of the object really bright and more or less indistinguishable from the background. You could disable the Ray Visibility for Diffuse, Glossy and Transmission under Object Properties > Visibility, but this will make the glass part really dark because the plane has no more effect on it.
So what I would suggest is, leave the plane as it is without any emission, but disable the Camera visibility in the Ray Visibility settings. This way it will effect the object so for example the glass is not too dark but not to bright either, but you can render with a transparent background:

Set the background to be rendered transparent in the Render Properties under Film, enable Transparent and also Transparent Glass:

Hit F12 to render and you get the object on a transparent background with the plane still affecting the object even though being invisible:

Now go to the Compositor, enable Use Nodes (and probably Backdrop to preview what you are doing). Get an Alpha Over node and plug the rendered image in the second Color input. Then get a simple Value node, set it to 15 or 16 and plug it into the first Color input. Now you have a completely white background without illuminating the object:

